# Unix. pecl memprof

Tags: freebsd

Im trying to install https://github.com/arnaud-lb/php-memory-profiler on FreeBSD 9.2

After pear install http://pecl.php.net/get/memprof-1.0.0.tgz

got such error:

```
    In file included from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_compile.h:690,
                 from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:26,
                 from /usr/local/include/php/main/php.h:38,
                 from /tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:19:
/usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_vm_opcodes.h:168:7: warning: no newline at end of file
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:37:3: error: #error "ZTS build not supported (yet)"
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:114:3: warning: #warning No support for malloc hooks, this build will not track persistent allocations
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'memprof_zend_execute_internal':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:695: error: too few arguments to function 'execute_internal'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:697: error: too few arguments to function 'old_zend_execute_internal'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'OnChangeMemoryLimit':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:724: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:726: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'memprof_enable':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:744: error: too few arguments to function 'is_zend_mm'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:751: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'memprof_disable':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:773: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'zm_startup_memprof':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:899: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_register_functions'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'zif_memprof_memory_get_usage':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1297: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1298: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_memory_usage'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1299: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1301: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_memory_usage'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c: In function 'zif_memprof_memory_get_peak_usage':
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1317: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1318: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_memory_peak_usage'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1319: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_mm_set_heap'
/tmp/pear/memprof/memprof.c:1321: error: too few arguments to function 'zend_memory_peak_usage'
*** [memprof.lo] Error code 1

Stop in /tmp/pear/pear-build-ranielrLVRCS/memprof-1.0.0.
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Other pecl, and php modules and extensions is ok.
On Debian wheezy install ok too.
Some problem with FreeBSD or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> memprof.c:37:3: error: #error "ZTS build not supported (yet)"

memprof doesn't support ZTS builds of PHP. This means that PHP has been built with the `--enable-maintainer-zts` option, and memprof doesn't support this.

You should build PHP without the `--enable-maintainer-zts` switch. This switch is only required if you use a PHP as server module in a threaded server (e.g. mod_php in apache's worker mpm), which is not recommended.

Comment: Ty, we will try it later, cuz dont wanna rebuild php and mod_php just right now. But i think u fully correct